# MySQL C++ Connector crashes my app at ResultSet->getString()

Tags: c++, crash, mysql-connector

It's me again probably asking noob C++ questions

I had MAJOR headaches making the darn (sorry for the language) MySQL C++ connector work. I don't know if it is poorly written or something, but for my experience yet I've never had so much trouble making something to work.

Anyhow I got it to connect and throw exceptions on failed connect/query which for me is quite big thing :U :P . The actual problem comes out of me obtaining the result of the query. Regardless of what I do my application always crashes :S

I used the 32-bit installer and the libmysql.dll/lib from the 32-bit MySQL server (since i'm compiling a 32-bit application i figured this is the right thing to do)

Here's some code so you could imagine what I'm talking about

**DBManager.h**

```
#ifndef DBMANAGER_H
#define DBMANAGER_H
#define CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC
#define CPPCONN_LIB_BUILD True

#include <string>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

class DBManager
{
public:
    static DBManager* Instance();
    bool Query(const char* Query);
    void Connect(const char* DbHost, unsigned short DbPort, const char* DbUser, const char* DbPass, const char* DbName);
    bool ValidCredentials(const char* Username, const char* Password);
    void ManageException(sql::SQLException &e);

    ~DBManager();

protected:
    static DBManager* pInstance;

private:
    DBManager() {};
    DBManager(DBManager const&){};
    DBManager& operator=(DBManager const&){};

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection *Con;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::Statement *stmt;

    bool isConnected;
};

#endif
```

And now the cpp file **DBManager.cpp**

```
#include "DBManager.h"

DBManager* DBManager::pInstance = NULL;

DBManager* DBManager::Instance()
{
    if (!pInstance)
    {
        pInstance = new DBManager();
    }

    return pInstance;
}

bool DBManager::Query(const char* Query)
{
    return true;
}

DBManager::~DBManager()
{   
    delete Con;
    delete pstmt;
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
}

void DBManager::ManageException(sql::SQLException& e)
{
    if (e.getErrorCode() != 0) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }
}

void DBManager::Connect(const char* DbHost, unsigned short DbPort, const char* DbUser, const char* DbPass, const char* DbName)
{
    try {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
        std::string connDSN = "tcp://" + std::string(DbHost) + ":3306";

        Con = driver->connect(connDSN, sql::SQLString(DbUser), sql::SQLString(DbPass));
        Con->setSchema(sql::SQLString(DbName));
        isConnected = true;

        std::cout<<"Database connection successul."<<std::endl;

    } catch(sql::SQLException &e) {
        ManageException(e);
        isConnected = false;

        return;
    }
}

bool DBManager::ValidCredentials(const char* Username, const char* Password)
{
    bool cred = false;

    try {
        pstmt = Con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_name=? LIMIT 1"); // Smart use of indexing
        pstmt->setString(1, Username);
        res = pstmt->executeQuery();

        while(res->next())
        {
            if (res->getString("password") == Password)
            {
                cred = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(sql::SQLException &e) {
        ManageException(e);
        return false;
    }

    return cred;
}
```

Basically, It compiles without a problem, Connects without a problem, Executes queries without a problem, but the second I try to retrieve data some breakpoint exception is thrown in a file "xutils.cpp". I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the DEBUG libraries while compiling for debug. Hmm libmysql.dll should be release since I extracted it from the server bundle, but I don't seem to find it as a source to compile my own.

I really have no idea why it crashes and burn like that :/

PS: Don't mind the no hashing of the password, it really is just a proof of concept to me in the way of ... getting it to work first, then securing it :U

PS: I also have Boost libraries compiled and ready in the project, if that would help :U

EDIT: Main function

```
bool ServerRunning = true;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
        std::string title = TEXT("Window Title Change");
        SetConsoleTitle(title.c_str());
    #endif;

    std::cout<<"Loading Configuration File..."<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    std::string path = boost::filesystem::path(boost::filesystem::current_path()).string();
    path += "\\Config.ini";

    INIParser* Config = new INIParser(path.c_str()); //MinINI

    // Sockets data
    std::string listenIP = Config->GetString("Network", "ListenIP", "127.0.0.1");
    unsigned short listenPort = Config->GetInt("Network", "ListenPort", 5000);

    // Database data
    std::string dbHost = Config->GetString("Database", "Host", "localhost");
    std::string dbUser = Config->GetString("Database", "User", "root");
    std::string dbPass = Config->GetString("Database", "Password", "");
    std::string dbName = Config->GetString("Database", "Database", "authserv");
    unsigned short dbPort = Config->GetInt("Database", "Post", 1000);

    // General settings
    int sessionTimeout = Config->GetInt("Settings", "SessionTimeout", 10);
    int maxClients = Config->GetInt("Settings", "MaxClients", 10);
    int serverTimeout = Config->GetInt("Settings", "GameserverTimeout", 1);

     // Begin Initialization
     DBManager::Instance()->Connect(dbHost.c_str(), dbPort, dbUser.c_str(), dbPass.c_str(), dbName.c_str());
     bool loginSuccess = DBManager::Instance()->ValidCredentials("Username", "Password");

    char c;
    while (ServerRunning)
    {
        std::cin>>c;

        if (c == 'q')
        {
            ServerRunning = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can i see that exception?

Comment: Well I uploaded the image here http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2415/mysqlcrash.jpg

Hope that helps further :U It makes no sense to me as it is x.x

Comment: I'm looking at this ... can you also post your main() function?  Note: you're allocating your statement conceivably more than once without deleting between.

Comment: Updated the main post, at the bottom, with my main() function

Comment: Is the `password` column defined as `varchar` in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `password` field is defined as `varchar` in the database, you cannot use `getString()` to retrieve it.  You must instead use the `blob` function, `getBlob()`.

This is how the `while` loop would look:

```
while(res->next())
{
    std::istream * retrievedPassword_stream = res->getBlob("password");
    if (retrievedPassword_stream)
    {
        char pws[PASSWORD_LENGTH+1]; // PASSWORD_LENGTH defined elsewhere; or use other functions to retrieve it
        retrievedPassword_stream->getline(pws, PASSWORD_LENGTH);
        std::string retrievedPassword(pws); // also, should handle case where Password length > PASSWORD_LENGTH
        if (retrievedPassword == std::string(Password))
        {
            cred = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Side comments:** Note that there are some other issues with the code.

- The statement handle must be deleted, so you should do a `delete pstmt;` at the appropriate place in the `ValidCredentials()` function (rather than in the destructor).  (But, why use a prepared statement in that case anyways?  Better to *initialize* the prepared statement in the constructor (or somewhere else outside the function the query is called), as well as delete in the destructor or elsewhere, if you *do* use a prepared statement.  Instead of a prepared statement, though, note that prepared statements are most useful for very high-use and high-CPU intensive queries, so using it for password validation might not be important here (you could just execute a regular query, instead of a prepared statement).)
- Likewise, the ResultSet needs to be deleted (`delete res`) at the end of the try block, rather than in the destructor.
- Be sure to check for NULL before using `pstmt`, `res`, or `Con`.
- `stmt` appears to be unused and should not be deleted.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the answers mate. Wish I could upvote you more than once for this answer. I could've never figured that this was the problem. Do you have any tips for me on how to debug in such cases? I really had no idea its column type thing, I thought my library I used to compile was flawed or something x.x

Comment: Documentation for the C++ API for the MySQL connector is very sparse, as you've seen, so it has to be figured out as you go along, in large part.  In this case, I set up a dummy database trying to emulate this issue, and simultaneously I looked at all of the available functions that could be called on the ResultSet object `res` (Visual Studio's intellisense made that easier). When I noticed the `getBlob()` function was an option, I put two-and-two together with the `varchar` field type that people usually create for text strings, and then tried that. It worked. I wish there were a magic trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. download mysql c++ connector
2. compile mysqlcppconn-static project use mt or mtd
3. your project add CPPCONN_LIB_BUILD
4. your project add (2) built static library