# can't read string data from DB

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I have MySQL 5.6 with connector c++ 1.1.3. My problem is that I can't display string data from my table while data of i.e INT can list without any problem. Please look at this:

```
/* INSERT TUTORIAL CODE HERE! */
sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
std::auto_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "pass"));
con->setSchema("mybase");
std::auto_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());

//example from dev/mysql site

stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mcountry");
stmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_ctry");
stmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getdata");

stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE mcountry(country_id INT)");
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE add_ctry(IN cname INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO mcountry(country_name) VALUES (cname); END;");
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE getdata() BEGIN SELECT * FROM mcountry; END;");

stmt->execute("CALL add_ctry(112)");
stmt->execute("CALL add_ctry(323)");

stmt->execute("CALL getdata()");

std::auto_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

do{
res.reset(stmt->getResultSet());
while(res->next())
{
cout << "ID: " << res->getInt(1);
}
} while(stmt->getMoreResults());
```

And this work great. Problem is when I change variable from INT to CHAR(somevalue) like this:

```
sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
std::auto_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "pass"));
con->setSchema("mybase");
std::auto_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());

//example from dev/mysql site

stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mcountry");
stmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_ctry");
stmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getdata");

stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE mcountry(country_name CHAR(3))");
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE add_ctry(IN cname CHAR(3)) BEGIN INSERT INTO mcountry(country_name) VALUES (cname); END;");
stmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE getdata() BEGIN SELECT * FROM mcountry; END;");

stmt->execute("CALL add_ctry('abc')");
stmt->execute("CALL add_ctry('def')");

stmt->execute("CALL getdata()");

std::auto_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res;

string str;

do{
res.reset(stmt->getResultSet());
while(res->next())
{
//cout << "Name: " << res->getString(1);
  str = res->getString(1);
  cout << str; //now instead of abc and def i get NON ASCI character
}
} while(stmt->getMoreResults());
```

And i'm getting error: Unhandled exception at 0x70481174 in tstproj.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00221000.

And VS2010 redirect me to string standard header and there indicate on:

```
if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
            && _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputn(_Str.c_str(), _Size) != (streamsize)_Size)
                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
```

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Off-topic: std::auto_ptr... seriously? There are people using it?

Comment: Seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839195/2077394