# c++ heap error using mysql 1.0.5

Tags: c++, mysql

I am testing mysql in c++ and load a simple table with 4 columns and store them in a map. I am getting a heap error `HEAP[mysql.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 0E510000, 002C7238 )`.

```
//=================================
// include guard
#pragma once

//=================================
// forward declared dependencies
//class Foo;
//class Bar;

//=================================
// included dependencies
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

//=================================
// the actual class
class DBO{
protected:
    //getters & setter variables
    std::string Table;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> Fields;

    //internal uses
    std::string UserName;
    std::string Password;
    std::string DB; 
    std::stringstream rowcount;
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::ResultSetMetaData *res_meta;
public:
    //Constructors
    DBO(void){}
    DBO(std::string TableVal){
        Table = TableVal;       
    }

    void connect(){
        UserName = "myuser";
        Password = "mypass";
        DB = "mydb";
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", UserName, Password);
    }

    void close(){
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
    }

    void test(){        
        try {   
            connect();
            con->setSchema(DB);
            stmt = con->createStatement();
            res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table + " LIMIT 1");
            res_meta = res->getMetaData();

            for(int i=1;i<=res_meta->getColumnCount();i++){
                _cout(res_meta->getColumnName(i));
                //_cout(res_meta->getColumnType(i));
                Fields.insert( std::pair<std::string,std::string>(res_meta->getColumnName(i),"test") );
            }         
            while (res->next()) {
                for (std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it=Fields.begin(); it!=Fields.end(); ++it){
                    Fields[it->first] = res->getString(it->first); //this throws error
                    //it->second = res->getString(it->first); this throws error also
                    _cout(it->first+": "+it->second);
                }
            }           
        } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
            _cout("#ERR: SQLException in ");
            _cout(e.what());
            _cout(e.getSQLState());
        }
        close();
    }
    void _cout(std::string out){
        dbPrint(const_cast<char *>(out.c_str()));
    }
};//END OF CLASS
```

Edit: I changed the message because it was unrelated to the runtime. I have found that the error is thrown using a varchar field with an email address of about 20 characters. After testing this out further it seems that any field with 15ish or more characters will throw the error. I tried to research possibilities and it sounds like it might not allocate enough memory. How would I allocate more memory or fix the problem if it is not a memory issue? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your column is defined as `varchar` in the database, you **`cannot use getString()`** to retrieve it. You must instead use the **`blob function, getBlob()`**.

You can refer this [getblob() for getting varchar column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832958/mysql-c-connector-crashes-my-app-at-resultset-getstring)